# How to convert String into HTML readable ASCII character

Tags: java, character, ascii

I am trying to convert Java String into HTML readable code.
For Example: H e l l o W o r l d as `&#x48 &#x65 &#x6c &#x6c &#x6f &#x57 &#x6f &#x72 &#x6c &#x64`

What I did so far:

```
    private static String convertToAscii(String str) {
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            str += "&#"+(int)str.charAt(i);
        }
    return str;
    }
```

its taking too much time plus processor fan making noice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gif is not a perfect representation of what's happening here, but it gets the basic idea[image]

Over here...

```
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
```

...You are looping through the String named `str`.

But here...

```
str += ...
```

...You are ***adding*** to str.

You are trying to get to the end of str, but you are literally adding to str for each loop. You have created an infinite loop.

Add to a different String. Like this.

```
   private static String convertToAscii(String str) {
   
      String output = "";
   
      for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
         output += "&#"+(int)str.charAt(i);
      }
         
      return output;
   
   }
```

Comment: And in case you don't get the joke, once Gromit's box runs out of train tracks to put down, he will get a StackOverflow error, just like you.

Comment: @davidalayachew: he'd get an `OutOfMemoryError` (`OutOfTrainTracksError`?), since there's no recursion happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like that:

```
private static String convertToAscii(String str) { 
    return str     
              .chars() 
              .boxed()
              .reduce("", (subRes, currVal) -> subRes + "&#" + currVal + ";" , (subVal, mappedVal) -> subVal + "" + mappedVal);
```

Its quicker with Java >= 8